# WordPress Sessions - Sticky forms

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I don't fully understand WordPress programming but using a few online articles and looking though  various forums (including this one) I've managed to set up a series of forms in their own pages in WP. The idea is that when the first form is completed the data is submitted to the second form page. The page template for the 2nd page grabs the data and stores it in session variables for later use (eg. to display some of the data entered earlier for reference purposes. Using the code shown below I've got this working.

My problem is that I also want users to be able to go BACK from the second form page to the first form page to edit data previously entered. I think this is called a 'sticky' form.

How do I achieve this?

Currently, my session code works if I go forward in the the series of form pages BUT if I navigate back to form 1 from form 2 the data is lost.

In my functions.php file I've got the following code which initiates a session:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

In the page templates for form page 2 I've got code which grabs incoming data from page 1 and stores it in session variables:

```
<?php

/*  Template Name: Form Page 2 */

$_SESSION['text_1'] = $_REQUEST['text_1'];
$_SESSION['text_2'] = $_REQUEST['text_2'];
$_SESSION['text_3'] = $_REQUEST['text_3'];
$_SESSION['text_4'] = $_REQUEST['text_4'];


get_header(); 

... etc.
```

On form Page 1 I have used a plugin to allow me to insert PHP code snippets as shortcodes.

In a textarea on form page 1 I've added a shortcode that contains the following PHP:

```
<textarea id="text_1" name="text_1" required rows="5">[php snippet=9]    </textarea>
```

Shortcode code (snippet=9):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['text_1'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['text_1'];
}
```

This works when I am moving from form page 1 to form page 2 (data in the session variables can be accessed but, if I go back (say, I'm on page2 and  want to go back to edit data on page 1) the data is lost (it doesn't show in the textarea).

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to use sessions in WP or whether there is some better way to do this.

Hoping someone can help me.

Comment: Try removing the destroy function of your code

Comment: Quebrando - Tried this but didn't work.